# Python - How to import functions?

Tags: python, syntax, import

models.py

```
def operation(argument):
            #Operation
    return variable

    class X(models.Model)
        a = models ...
        b = models ...
```

I am trying to import operation in my views.py .. When I try using

```
from project.models import operation
```

But then I get the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name operation
```

Comment: I noticed my mistake but my actual problem is that operation is a global function
`def operation:
'''Operations'''
    return variable
class X(models.Model):
#
#`

Comment: This is not a Django question but a Python question

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/* */` aren't valid comment characters in python, which is causes a parse error, so the import fails.  Use `#` instead.

Also, you'll want to get an instance of `X` then call the `operation` method on that.  Like:

```
from myproj.models import X
x = X.objects.get(id=1)
val = x.operation()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to import the class to get access to the instance method you've defined on the class.